# How to remove an AWS Instance volume using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, terraform

I deploy a CentOS 7 using an AMI that automatically creates a volume on AWS, so when I remove the platform using the next Terraform commands:

```
terraform plan -destroy -var-file terraform.tfvars -out terraform.tfplan
terraform apply terraform.tfplan
```

The volume doesn't remove because it was created automatically with the AMI and terraform doesn't create it. Is it possible to remove with terraform?

My AWS instance is created with the next terraform code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "DCOS-master1" {
    ami = "${var.aws_centos_ami}"
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"
    instance_type = "t2.medium"
    key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.bastion.id}"]
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    private_ip = "10.0.0.11"
    source_dest_check = false
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.eu-west-1b-public.id}"

    tags {
            Name = "master1"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the next code to get information about the EBS volume and to take its ID:

```
data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "attachment.instance-id"
    values = ["${aws_instance.DCOS-master1.id}"]
  }
}

output "ebs_volume_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.id}"
}
```

Then having the EBS volume ID I import to the terraform plan using:

```
terraform import aws_ebs_volume.data volume-ID
```

Finally when I run `terraform destroy` all the instances and volumes are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

if the EBS is protected you need to manually remove the termination protection first on the console then you can destroy it

Comment: But I can remove it manually, on the AWS volumes. I have a full automatized deployment and destroy of data platform on cloud using terraform and ansible. I need to remove it with terraform automatically. Is it not possible?

Comment: if you don't protect your ebs this is possible be careful though

Comment: But if I don't protect it would be accesible from anyone? Or only it would be unprotected for my AWS account?

Comment: are you creating a ebs backed instance? with termination protection?

Comment: I add the terraform code that I use to create one instance to the question, there you could see that I don't create any protection.

Comment: I see try `terraform refresh` and  `terraform destroy` command

Comment: I try it but the volume persist.. maybe on the refresh it doesn't detect the volume as some new configuration of the infraestructure..

Comment: I think "DCOS-master1" identier, is changed or not detected properly,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138068/discussion-between-kenichi-shibata-and-asier).